# Amazon Textract skip some form fields when doing analysis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

I am calling Amazon Textract api for analyze pdf scanned image and it skipped some fields as key value pair. Is there any way to train or specifically point to map key value pair properly?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no capability to 'train' Amazon Textract.

Available actions are shown on: [Actions - Amazon Textract](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_Operations.html)